# How to build/run Golang and SPA frameworks such as ReactJs/VueJs on the same IDE?

Tags: node.js, go, vue.js, build, ide

Just like the latest Visual Studio 2017, .NetCore2(backend) and an SPA(frontend) can be build under one command or under one Project. I think Microsoft team managed to implement the building tool for backend and frontend at the same build command.
I am looking for an IDE or a plugin or any way that can do such feat with GoLang(backend) and VueJS(frontend).

Comment: try VSCode with go plugin is really nice and have a lot of snippets https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am currently using VSCode but still can't find the way to build both GoLang and VueJs project.

Comment: Well you need to build separately but the good point for vscode is that the terminal is integrated on it , so you don't need to open 2 apps for do it. If you are looking for a "start app" command that build both applications I think doesn't exist. The unique idea that I'm thinking is creating a makefile

Answer (score 0):

### Coding

All Jetbrains products provide their official [Vue.js plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9442-vue-js). I'm using [GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) and this plugin to achieve what you need.

### Running

I open up two terminals inside the IDE. Then I start the client and server separately.

Comment: I haven't try any Jetbrains products but by opening two terminals defeat a purpose of just one build command. Note: I have no problem with multiple terminals open, if I'm the only person who will develop a project. I need to present a simple IDE integration for others to follow.

Comment: Since they are two different servers you need two different commands. You may use a bash script to start both simultaneously, though. By building you mean production ready code or development?

Comment: Building for both development and production ready. Our team is using an Eclipse IDE as most of our projects were developed in Java. Since I am in charge to migrate our Java projects to GoLang, my boss would like an IDE that is almost similar to Eclipse in terms of compiling/building/debugging. I was hoping there's a similar way like build.xml.

Comment: Can't say anything about `build.xml` but GoLand has so many built-in tools for debugging/compiling. Most times it's a one click. Same goes for Vue.js integration. You can test GoLand for free by the way.